# Magento product check if price is below 30

Tags: product

I want to add a php line to my /product/view.phtml file.

I want to check if the price of the product is below 30.

How can I achieve that?

I tried this, but that does not work:

```
<?php if(inval($_product->getFinalPrice()) < 30): ?>
<p>test</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>test 2</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** change to

```
<?php if(intval($_product->getFinalPrice()) < 30): ?>
```

**from**

```
<?php if $_product->getFinalPrice() < 30.00 ?>
```

***Final price always  less then or   equal to price***

```
<?php if(intval($_product->getFinalPrice()) < 30): ?>
<p>test</p>
<?php else: ?>
<p>test 2</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit. I tried that, but that does break down the product view page.

Comment: Can u please share code of view.phtml

Comment: See my edit in the question.

Comment: oops, done a silly mistake  `inval` to `intval`>now check